# xdebug var_dump function colors

Tags: xdebug, var-dump

I have installed xdebug on my computer with windows and it works fine by default - traces are colorfull and pretty but on another computer with ubuntu 10.10 its colourless and without any formatting.
I tryed fill xdebug formatting parameters in php.ini but it didn't work for me :(

What I need to make for improving output formatting?

Comment: A PHP patch about this was accepted yesterday: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/error-formatting-for-developers Regards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced this problem once upon a time and turned out to be :

open `php.ini` and look for `html_errors` in your case it should be `off`

, so simply turn it `on` and restart your apache

and you would be good to go :)