# Configure xDebug on Linux for PHP5

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, configuration, xdebug

I, as far as I can tell, have set up xDebug to work on my local machine, however it, obviously, is not. I am trying to go from

[image: without xdebug]

to

[image: with xdebug].

Who cares? The second image is with xDebug working, which afaik, means I can get stack traces etc to work. Help!

I followed the install instructions at the xdebug site. I have included the following in my /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file:

```
zend_extension=/etc/php5/xdebug/xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
xdebug.collect_vars = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 4
```

When viewing phpinfo(), I get:

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

Furthermore, below that in the modules section I see that xDebug with it's settings is there.

However I can't get seem to get xDebug to show any information on my pages when there are bugs?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xdebug doesn't format output.

Make sure you have PHP's **html_errors** set to 1 in php.ini

- [Does xdebug beautify var_dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678389/does-xdebug-beautify-var-dump)
- [xdebug var_dump function colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534312/xdebug-var-dump-function-colors)

Comment: The error i've pasted is in fact a PHP error, I put it there on purpose to see if i'd get a stack trace or some similar xDebug output. Instead i'm still getting PHP5 errors, which is not what I want. I knw the cause of the error. This question is more about setting up xDebug correctly to show errors on pages.

Comment: Mahbubur, you rock. Thank you!